# Is there a way to remove the loader (white screen) when loading the page in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```html
<div style="position:relative;width:fit-content;height:fit-content;">
            <a style="position:absolute;top:20px;right:1rem;opacity:0.8;" href="https://clipchamp.com/watch/Eppk7v1l0gO?utm_source=embed&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=watch">
                <img style="height:22px;" src="https://clipchamp.com/e.svg" alt="Made with Clipchamp" />
            </a>
            <iframe allowfullscreen style="border:none" src="https://clipchamp.com/watch/Eppk7v1l0gO/embed" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
        </div>
```

I would like to remove that screen and once I enter my home page, I don't have to go through a blank screen, I have done a lot of research, I hope someone can help me, thanks

Comment: that's splash screen, you can change color and include logo or (custom animation while loading)->(including custom css)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I don't want any of that, I just want it to load the other screen instead of the loading screen.

Comment: while flutter provide web app(not site), it will take some time to fetch, as much as i know, you can optimize the loading, but loading will take a place for any

Comment: I hope that flutter will provide it one day, I would like it because it gives my page more normality and I don't have to make my clients wait.

Comment: It has to download quite a bit amount of JavaScript code, install service worker etc., so I am afraid this delay will stay with us. As @YeasinSheikh commented the best way is to customize it, I suggest [this packace](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash), it works on web as well.